# How do I turn off iOS from registering my finger while annotating?

Tags: ios, ipad, apple-pencil

I have the iPad pro 2020 and the apple pencil. When marking up a document (say, in Notes or Files) I want to be able to disable annotation inputs from my finger - When I'm in annotation mode I only want the iPad to detect inputs from the pencil for annotation. Ie, I don't want stray finger movements to result in marks. How do I set this? Notability has this functionality. Surely iOS must as well?

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways to address this.

In Notes or any similar app you can make app-specific adjustments.  Select the Markup icon at the top of the screen (looks like a pencil tip). That will open the Markup toolbar, usually at the bottom of the screen.

[image]

- Yes, I know this is not an iPad Pro from 2020 but it's a good picture so I used it anyway.

Tap the 3 dots and turn off 'Draw with finger'.

The other way is to make the change at a global level.  Go to `Settings -> Apple Pencil` and turn off "Only Draw with Apple Pencil".